# rails: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `division_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I am working on a simple support ticket system , however I'm getting a weird error. Here is the error :

**ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `division_id`**

and here is the code :

user.rb:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :division
  has_many :teckets
  has_many :teckets , through: :user_tecket

  has_secure_password
end
```

division.rb:

```
 class Division < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :users, through: :user_division
  has_many :teckets
  has_many :teckets, through: :teckets_divisions
end
```

tecket.rb :

```
class Tecket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :status
  has_one :status, through: :tecket_statuses
end
```

teckets_division.rb :

```
class TecketsDivision < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tecket
  belongs_to :division
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171001063612) do

  create_table "divisions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "replies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tecket_replies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tecket_id"
    t.integer "reply_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tecket_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tecket_id"
    t.integer "status_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "teckets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "content"
    t.string "platform"
    t.string "version"
    t.string "client_anme"
    t.string "client_phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "teckets_divisions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tecket_id"
    t.integer "division_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "user_divisions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "division_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "user_teckets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "tecket_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "passwrod"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.integer "division_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**I get the error when I try to create a user from the console**

**Edit :** I have added the schema.rb file as requested

Comment: please include the contents of `db/schema.rb` in your question

Comment: @ImranAli Thanks , I have included the file

Comment: also include the contents of `app/models/user.rb`

Comment: @ImranAli I have added the user.rb too , thanks

Comment: @keloazoldik show how your are creating user. I mean controller action

Comment: @krishnar OP has mentioned he is trying to create a record from console

Comment: Ok.. thats what how he is creating user.. whether in controller/console.But how???

Comment: Either way, is anyone else confused by the number of redundant associations? looks pretty muddy and may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either remove the division_id from the user table and `has_many :users` from divisions model

or (and the simpler approach),

remove user_divisions join table and this line from division model:

`has_many :users, through: :user_division`

also - You have a lot of join tables it seems, but I don't see the need for their use.  You could direct relate them in most of the cases you have shown.